# Match regex named group up until optional word

Tags: regex, regex-group, splunk

I have these strings that I want to grab some information from them using a Regex.

`Vuln : Upgrade pypi://onnx from 1.12.0 to 1.13.0 Final`

`Vuln : Upgrade gav://com.google.guava:guava from 22.0 to 32.0.0-android for github.com/blah/blah` (Need to capture `gav://com.google.guava:guava` `22.0` `32.0.0-android`)

`Vuln : Upgrade gav://org.apache.avro:avro from 1.11.1 for Android to 1.11.3 Final for github.com/blah/blah` (Need to capture `gav://org.apache.avro:avro` `1.11.1 for Android` `1.11.3 Final`)

I specifically just need to grab the strings `pypi://onnx` `1.12.0` `1.13.0 Final` for example which are the library and version names since I'm using Splunk and the capture groups can become variables, all of these strings are dynamic, they will not always be what it is above.

I've been having difficulty crafting a regex that stops the moment the `for` is encountered, since it can be optional.

This is the one I've tried

```
Vuln : Upgrade\s*(?<vulnNameFromTo>.+)\sfrom\s*(?<vulnCurrentVersionFromTo>.+)\sto\s(?<vulnFixVersionFromTo>.+)(?:\sfor\s)?
```

But the last named capture group, grabs everything and the for and that's not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean you want grab a certain string? If you wish to simply determine whether it is present there is no point in returning it, or do wish to, say, replace it with other text?

Comment: I think you need a regex where `for` + the rest of string is matched as an optional pattern till the end of the string, so that there is either `for` + anything or end of string. I tried to implement this logic in my answer, I'd be happy to hear your thoughts on this approach.

Comment: So I'm using Splunk and this uses a language called SPL which has a command that supports regular regex, when you use a named capture group, that capture group becomes a variable that I can use later, that's what I mean when I say "grab" the string from the named capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Vuln : Upgrade\s*(?<vulnNameFromTo>.*?)\s+from\s+(?<vulnCurrentVersionFromTo>.*?)\s+to\s+(?<vulnFixVersionFromTo>.+?)(?:\s+for\b.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/te0pnK/2).

*Details*:

- `Vuln : Upgrade` - a literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<vulnNameFromTo>.*?)` - Group "vulnNameFromTo": one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+from\s+` - `from` string enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(?<vulnCurrentVersionFromTo>.*?)` - Group "vulnCurrentVersionFromTo": one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+to\s+` - `to` word enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `(?<vulnFixVersionFromTo>.+?)` - Group "vulnFixVersionFromTo": any one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+for\b.*)?` - an optional sequence of one or more whitespaces, `for`, a word boundary and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This seems to be working great, the only modification is that I did ((?<vulnNameFromTo>.+?)\s+from\s+(?<vulnCurrentVersionFromTo>.+?) since all named capture groups can also have spaces for other words up until the static texts

Comment: @bojackhorseman99 Fixed, see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^Vuln\h+:\h+Upgrade\h+(?P<pypi>\S+)\h+from\h+(?P<ini_v>[0-9.]+)\h+to\h+(?P<final_v>[0-9.]+\h+Final)
```

See: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9hwoxX/latest)

...or try this run-anywhere example SPL:

````
| makeresults
| eval a=split("Vuln : Upgrade pypi://onnx from 1.12.0 to 1.13.0 Final#Vuln : Upgrade pypi://onnx from 1.12.0 to 1.13.0 Final for github.com/blah/blah","#")
| mvexpand a
| table a
```actual extraction```
| rex field=a "^Vuln\h+:\h+Upgrade\h+(?P<pypi>\S+)\h+from\h+(?P<ini_v>[0-9.]+)\h+to\h+(?P<final_v>[0-9.]+\h+Final)"
````

---

Explanation

- `^Vuln\h+:\h+Upgrade\h+`: Static start to string: `Vuln : Upgrade`
- `(?P<pypi>\S+)`: grabs pipy part
- `\h+from\h+: static`  from `
- `(?P<ini_v>[0-9.]+)`: grabs the initial version
- `\h+to\h+`: static `to`
- `(?P<final_v>[0-9.]+\h+Final)`: grabs final version

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, but the strings that I want to grab are not constant are completely dynamic , everything else is static except what I want to grab, which are the library name and versions.

Comment: Then please do give a more refelctive sample in your question so that it can be applied for the answer

Comment: Just updated the initial post with some new examples, thanks